How to get my extension’s process ID of the dext for debugging with lldb
I follow this guide Debugging and testing system extensions, and try to debug my dext code.
In the Attach the debugger to your system extension, it said After your system extension launches, run the ps command-line tool and note your extension’s process ID.
This is the current output for my dext status
% systemextensionsctl list
1 extension(s)
--- com.apple.system_extension.driver_extension
enabled active  teamID  bundleID (version)  name    [state]
*   *   K3TDMD9Y6B  com.accusys.scsidriver (1.0/1)  com.accusys.scsidriver  [activated enabled]

and I used the ps command but nothing happen, I can not get my extension’s process ID.
ps aux | grep com.accusys.scsidriver

or
ps -ef | grep com.accusys.scsidriver

How to do that?
Any suggestion is appreciated.
